# Problem recovering from s2disk

Tags: hibernate

Occasionally, when I recover from s2disk, I get stuck with the following image being displayed on the monitor:

[image]

The only way out seems to be power cycling the machine.

It's an ASUS K42Jr laptop running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.  How do I go about looking for the cause of this problem?  Are there any log files that are likely to contain helpful hints?

Suspending using s2ram seems to work OK (provided I use the --force flag).

Answer (score 1):

If you can go to a command line using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> then restart X. Else rebooting is the only options.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Is there a way to solve this problem?  I'd really like a hibernate feature that works.

Comment: File a bug report =)